Is Prim's Greedy Algorithm special on the Cayley Graph of Coxeter Groups?
Given, a Coxeter System (W,S), equipped with a total order $ <_S $ on $S$, one can run Prim's Greedy Algorithm on the Cayley Graph of $(W,S)$, starting at the identity.
This generates a total order, that we denote $<_S^*$, on $W$ in the following way: we say $u <_S^* v$ if and only if $u$ were added to the generated spanning tree before $v$ when running the algorithm.
For example, if one were to do this for $A_2$, with $S = \{s_1, s_2\}$ and $s_1 <_S s_2$,  running the algorithm, step-by-step, would look something like so:
$A_2$" /> Here, s_1 is represented by the red edges, and s_2, by the blue edges. In this case $id <_S^* s_1 <_S^* s_2 <_S^* s_2s_1 <_S^* s_1s_2 <_S^* s_1s_2s_1$.
As one more example, the resulting graph for $B_3$ below for some choice of $<_S$.

Given any total ordering of $W$, $<_W$, one can define the induced Cayley embedding $ \varphi_{<_W} : W \hookrightarrow Sym(|W|) $ such that $(i)\varphi_{<_W}(w) = j$ if and only if $w$ sends the $i$th least element of $<_W$ to the $j$th least.
There appear to be lots of nice properties of the orders $<_S^*$ in general, for example, they are refinements of the Bruhat Order.
My (admittedly vague) question is:
Are there any properties of $\varphi_{<_S^*}$ with respect to the Bruhat order that distinguishes them from $\varphi_{<_W}$ for general refinements of the Bruhat Order, $<_W$?
